# Filter a two dimensional array in table view for searching in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, search

I have a two dimensional array

```
fileprivate var Food : [[FoodModel]] = [[]]

Food = [["Apple","Mango"],["Chocolate","Biscuit"]]
```

and two sections

```
let section = ["Fruits","Dry Food"]
```

for a table view. It's displaying the value nicely. Now I added a search bar for searching value from Food. My problem is that I can't filter Food by my searching keyword.

```
Food.filter({}) //what to write here?
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var searchResult = Food.flatMap({ $0 }).filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchedKeyword) }
```

Firstly, the `flatMap` flattens the array of array to single array, then filters to that resulting array.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
let searchString = "Choco"

var result = Food.filter { (dataArray:[FoodModel]) -> Bool in
    return dataArray.filter({ (FoodModel) -> Bool in
        return FoodModel.containsString(searchString)
    }).count > 0
}
```

Comment: what is dataArray ? I am trying to use it .